# How to read contents of MANIFEST.MF?

Tags: jakarta-ee, classpath

I have an EAR with a JAR with an EJB inside.

How can I read the contents of the file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF of the EAR ?

I'd like to do it from inside the EJB class.

In particular, how do I select between many possible META-INF/MANIFEST.MF files in the EAR and JAR ?

Answer (score 0):

The `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` is not accessible from applications because there is no class loader for the EAR.

On the other hand, all jars in the `lib` directory of an EAR file are made available in the same class loader, so you have no way of knowing which one that a ClassLoader.getResource(...) will return.

You need to iterate over them via [ClassLoader.findResources(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findResources-java.lang.String-)